# What are the assumptions for MANOVA and how I should apply it in R?

Tags: r, manova

I would like to analyze effect of a treatment on my patient samples by MANOVA in R. I have measurement of 3 different protein level for treated and untreated patients. Now I would like to analyze effect of my treatment on the whole different protein measurements and not each individually (sort of summing them up together). What are the assumptions for MANOVA and how I should apply it on my dataset in R?

An example line of my dataset:

```
        CD13    CD68     AT1     treatment
sample1 0.065   0.82     0.488   +
sample2 0       1.58     0.47    -
```

I have around 30 replicates for each treated and untreated patient group.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stuff is all very well documented on the Internet.

A rundown of MANOVA theory, assumptions start on page 2: http://userwww.sfsu.edu/efc/classes/biol710/manova/MANOVAnewest.pdf

A quick guide to (M)ANOVA in R: http://www.statmethods.net/stats/anova.html